# Java XML парсинг

Tags: java, xml, парсер, java-ee, xmlparser

Необходимо распарсить XML таким образом, чтобы захватить все данные/подтеги по заданному одному тегу. Например:

```
<root>
    <Response>
        <Data>
            <Item>something</Item>
            <Number>1</Number>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Item>book</Item>
            <Number>2</Number>
        </Data>
    </Response>
</root>
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы по заданному тегу, в данном случае Response взять следующий фрагмент XML:

```
<Response>
    <Data>
        <Item>something</Item>
        <Number>1</Number>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Item>book</Item>
        <Number>2</Number>
    </Data>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример получения NodeList по тегу:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    File f = new File("NewFile.xml");
    doc = db.parse(f);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Response");
```

nodes-список элементов "Response".Получить Node элемент из данного списка вы можете по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит следовать примеру товарища @Peter Slusar (Вы уж простите, но юзать стандартный парсер хмл в данный момент времени moveton).
Используем апи jdom2:

```
fro (Element element : doc.getRootElement.elements("Response")) {
//тело с парсингом параметров
}
```